# Is there a Winforms .Net Equivalent for Delphi's TDBNavigator?

Tags: c#, winforms, delphi, data-binding

Is there an analogue in winforms.net (C#) to Delphi's TDBNavigator control, that allows a user to go to the first record, last record, next record, previous record (and even go into edit, insert, and delete mode, possibly)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you are seeking is called a [BindingNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.aspx)